# Start a batch file and close Cmd once it is finished

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have my application spread over multiple directories, each containing a part (e.g. web frontend, mobile application, administration, middleware, backend, ...).

In each of the directories I have one part, and a file `compile.cmd` which compiles that part and looks roughly like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
compiler prepare thisPart
compiler compile thisPart
copy resultingFile1 ../bundleDirectory
     ...
copy resultingFileN ../bundleDirectory
pause
```

The "pause" is so I can check the compiler output, whether compile failed and which error messages occurred, and then close the window with a single keystroke (mostly, space key).

I now want to have a batch file that calls all these batch files for different application parts **in parallel**, so I guess I have to open a new shell window for each.

So I wrote `CompileAllParts.cmd` like this:

```
cd part1
start "Compile part 1" compile.cmd
cd ../part2
start "Compile part 2" compile.cmd
cd ../part3
start "Compile part 3" compile.cmd
```

Positive is that I can influence the window title, but the drawback is that new Cmds are spawned which do not automatically close.

This is also part of the documentation of `start`:

> If `command` is an internal cmd command or a batch file then the command processor is run with the /K switch to `cmd.exe`. This means that the window will remain after the command has been run.

Is there a hidden parameter to explicitly disable this behaviour?

Comment: you can use the `/B` switch of the start command to execute in the same cmd session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combine `start` with `cmd`. First to set title and working folder, second to use `/C` and execute the command:

```
start "Compile part 1" /d "part1" cmd /c "d:\proper folder\compile.cmd"
```